# Popover wont go to top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a popover using image as the link, using html and js, I need popover to be above the image but it is going to the middle (vertically) of the image

```html
<div class="container mt30 mb30" > 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <a data-toggle="popover1" data-img="https://www.ohm.co.uk/images/br12a3sys/ohm-brt-6-sys-2.png" title="BRT-6 System"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/br12a3sys/ohm-brt-6-sys.png" >
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
<script>
    $('[data-toggle="popover1"]').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover click',
        placement: 'top',
        content: function () { return '<img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" /><p>Solving compact portable audio by using 2 x BRW-26 1x BRS-12A3, 1 x BRS-12 and pole mounts that all fit in the back of a standard car. The system is light enough to carry, the whole system to be conveniently stacked and transported on the optional wheel board. </p> <p> An infinite amount of combinations are possible by linking more than one BRS-12A3 together for  larger projects. Where will your creativity take you?</p>'; }
    });
</script>
```

Expected result is that the popover is completley above the image link but the actual is that it is halfway down the image link.

Answer (score 3):

Anchor (a) tag is an inline element, so its not getting its area. You need to give display: inline-block to a to show popover on top of image.

> a {
>          display: inline-block;    }

This will solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using `data-placement="top"`

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>
```

Also check whether jquery ui exist in your code some times it creates conflicts

Comment: Hi thanks for your response Vikas,
I tried the href #  but this sent me right back to the top of my page,

Also I added the JS at the bottom of my page, sorry I am new to bootstrap and am unsure what you mean by checking the jquery ui exist in code. 

There is some kind of conflict as my js needs to call an imagine intot he popover, everything seems to work fine until I do this.

Comment: If `href` is causing a problem you can just remove that attribute.